# Should [han-shot-first] be shot first?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a tag for Han Solo himself, [han-solo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/han-solo), and a tag for the age old question of who shot first: [han-shot-first](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/han-shot-first).

**Should we make the latter a synonym of the former?**

Even though the latter has 8 questions, it seems a bit too specialised.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Let’s get rid of it

- **It doesn’t help with searching.** There’s [only one question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhan-shot-first%5D%20-%E2%80%9Dhan%20shot%20first%E2%80%9D) with [han-shot-first](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/han-shot-first) and not the phrase “Han shot first,” and it’s closed. There *is* arguably [one question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137244/did-chewie-reference-the-old-han-shot-first-debate-in-the-force-awakens) with “Han shot first” that lacks the tag and should have it, but that’s not particularly relevant. Anyone can just search for “Han shot first” (or even easier, “shot first”) and find all the relevant questions.
- No one’s going to subscribe to it. There’s no new information coming out about this matter at this point, and new questions are being posted at a rate of about two per year.
- It’s on only eight questions. Besides being a rather specialized tag, this makes it pretty easy to edit out.

Comment: Re your last bullet point: **no manual edits would be needed to get rid of this tag**. Since it's a franchise-specific tag, it could be smoothly and silently merged into [tag:star-wars] to make it disappear.

Comment: (Also, that's a pretty damn quick consensus you got there! *Time-travelling edit:* and a pretty damn quick response to my first comment too.)

Comment: @Randal’Thor - True.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Except that the tag synonym suggestion system is unworkable, and it pretty much always needs mods to enact them. Which if you're volunteering... :)

Comment: @curiousdannii Merged, not synonymised - which always needs a mod. And yes, I'm volunteering :-) Just going to wait a bit longer in case anyone comes up with an argument to keep the tag.

Comment: I've just done the merge and [meta-tag:status-completed] this. Not sure if you want to edit your answer to match.

Comment: @Randal’Thor - I think the [status-completed](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag is good enough.

Comment: Rand al'Thor burninated first!